# Add JSP Page to Spring Service

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a standalone REST service which uses Spring boot. Now I want to add some fontend on my project. My service is not complicated and it is base on [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). I don't have the web.xml file. What should I do to add a JSP page? What should I do in my controller? Do I have to add new files?

Comment: It has been ages since I touched Spring but I think you could return a `ModelAndView` instance and specify a JSP or even have it found by the container by convention.

Comment: why do you need jsp pages.if you work with rest services use html files and call your rest services from this html page

Comment: Because I want to add Spring security later.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a JSP page then rather than writing the response to the response stream you have to put the response in the model&view object & display in a jsp. Like a model view controller MVC Pattern. The architecture of your app will change, rather than being REST based it will be converted to a MVC architecture.

Another way is to keep sending the response in the response stream & parse the response on the client side. You can use jquery or any framework for that. I believe you can implement Spring security in this architecture without any problem. Spring security acts as a proxy/interceptor before it hits the controllers. You have to configure Spring security on the server side, when a request is made for a resource say a controller from the client side it will be first intercepted by spring security.

[Check this out](http://java.dzone.com/articles/securing-restful-web-service)